# Cast std::bind function pointer to void* and back

Tags: c++, casting, stdbind

Let's say I want to bind a function and then pass it to another function as a void *, and cast it back.

I have a global function in which I try to cast the function:

```
void function_wrapper(void * func){

std::function<void(const std::vector<double>&, const std::vector<double>&)> * function = reinterpret_cast<std::function<void(const std::vector<double>&, const std::vector<double>&)> *>(func);

std::function<void(const std::vector<double>&, const std::vector<double>&)> function_ = *function;
}
```

func, meanwhile, is created as:

```
auto func = std::bind(&MyObj<dim>::myfunc, this, _1, _2);
```

Here `dim` is a templated integer equal to `2` And `function_wrapper` is called via

```
function_wrapper((void *)(&func));
```

Meanwhile, `myfunc` is a method of `MyObj<dim>` with type:

```
void myfunc(const std::vector<double>& x, std::vector<double>& F) const;
```

When I try to call function_wrapper as described above, I get the following error when I dereference it:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.

std::_Func_class<void,std::vector<double,std::allocator<double> > const & __ptr64,std::vector<double,std::allocator<double> > const & __ptr64>::_Getimpl(...) returned 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

I presume I have the typing wrong of my cast, but I don't know the correct way to declare the type.  What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The result of a `std::bind` is not a `std::function`, as the shown code assumes.

As such, when the shown code casts the pointer to the return value from `std::bind` to a `void *`, then casts it back to a pointer to a `std::function`, then invokes or accesses the function object, this results in undefined behavior.

[func.bind.isbind] specifies `std::bind` as follows:

> template<class F, class... BoundArgs> *unspecified* bind(F&& f,
>   BoundArgs&&... bound_args);

With the return value of: "A forwarding call wrapper *g* with a weak result type (20.9.2). The effect of g(u1, u2, ..., uM) shall be INVOKE (fd, std::forward(v1), std::forward(v2), ..., std::forward(vN), result_of_t)".

That's it. The class returned by `std::bind` is unspecified, and although it is certainly permitted for a given C++ implementation to, somehow, produce a `std::function`, it is not required to do so.

But, the solution is simple: explicitly assign the return value from `std::bind` to an appropriate `std::function`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what is the solution here, exactly?  What should my return type be?  std::function is a templated type, and using the template I've chosen does not compile: "error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'"

Comment: As I wrote, the solution is to explicitly assign the return value from `std::bind` to the appropriate `std::function`, instead of `auto`.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess my confusion now is I don't know how to type the appropriate std::function, as the one I wrote is apparently not the right one :)

Comment: Think hard about what your end result from doing the bind is. You are getting a callable object that takes certain parameters, and return a specific type. That's your `std::function` right there.

Comment: Okay, let me try to be a little bit clearer.  I tried walking through the function signature of the bind.  I clearly did not get it right.  I spent a good amount of time playing around with different variations.  If you see what I am doing wrong in using std::function<void(const std::vector<double>&, const std::vector<double>&)> as the bind return type, please let me know.